# Can't format SD Disks on Apple Mac or delete data from SD Cards

Tags: mac, partitioning, sd-card, format

Summary:
No matter what I do, I can't seem to format an SD Card,  or even delete its data, on my 2021 M1 Mac Mini.  Here's what's happening:

I buy a new SD Card, and use Raspberry Pi Imager to burn an ISO to it.  Works perfectly, no problem.

But if I try to format that same card to use it for something else,  I can't do it at all.  Here is what I tried:

- Raspberry Pi Imager "Erase Disk" - fails.
- SD Formatter (from SDCard.org): - Fails
- Mac OS/X Disk Utility: - Seems to work, but fails.
- Deleting files seems to work, but after ejecting the SD card and re-inserting it, I see that the files are still there.
- I can't even change the name of the card.  It seems to change but once re-inserting it, the old name is still there.
- Formatting from the MacOS Shell.  When I try this I get this error: "Error: -69830: This operation requires an unmounted disk".
- I also tried  sudo diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ UntitledUFS /dev/disk4. No errors, but no results either.

Here's what I know it is not:

- The computer or reader.  The same issue happens on 2 different computers (both running Mac OS/X Montrey, but this happened with the previous version of macOS too).
- The SD Cards themselves.  The exact same thing has happened on 3 different SD cards now.  All new.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a common failure mode of sd cards. Replace it.

Comment: Some SD cards do seem to go read only if certain tools are used to write them as you have done. Are these branded cards or cheap generic cards? If they are from a reputable brand then you might need to contact the manufacturer or supplier.